# Cursor returns 1 extra records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
I have a legacy code which used a Table called MyTable which **has only 6 records**.

Here is SQl code:

USe MyDatabase
GO

DECLARE @ANubmer as  Varchar(100)
DECLARE @BNumber as Varchar(100)


DECLARE MyCursor  CURSOR FOR
SELECT Anumber,BNumber
 FROM MyTable
 ORDER BY 
 s.ANumber,date1

OPEN SurveyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber

 select 'CID='+@ANumber+' Avatar='+ @BNubmer


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber                   

 select 'CID='+@ANumber+' Avatar='+ @BNubmer
END
```

The problem is above code **returns 7 rows.**

Comment: Since you have to fix this anyway why not get rid of the cursor entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the second 'FETCH' below the 'select' statement in the loop.
Essentially, it should be the last statement in the 'while' loop.

Also...ditch the first select statement.  You should just have everything in the one loop.

*Fetch -> while -> select -> fetch*

```
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN



     select 'CID='+@ANumber+' Avatar='+ @BNubmer

     FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber
    END
```

**Full Script Corrected**

```
USe MyDatabase
GO

DECLARE @ANubmer as  Varchar(100)
DECLARE @BNumber as Varchar(100)


DECLARE MyCursor  CURSOR FOR
SELECT Anumber,BNumber
 FROM MyTable
 ORDER BY 
 s.ANumber,date1

OPEN SurveyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


 select 'CID='+@ANumber+' Avatar='+ @BNubmer


 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber 
END
```

**Suggested Refinements**

- One fetch statement using GOTO
- Close/Deallocate added

  ```
  USe MyDatabase
  GO

  DECLARE @ANubmer as  Varchar(100)
  DECLARE @BNumber as Varchar(100)


  DECLARE MyCursor  CURSOR FOR
  SELECT Anumber,BNumber
   FROM MyTable
   ORDER BY 
   s.ANumber,date1

  OPEN SurveyCursor

  GOTO FetchNext;


  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN


   select 'CID='+@ANumber+' Avatar='+ @BNubmer

  FetchNext:
   FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @ANubmer, @BNumber 
  END

  CLOSE MyCursor
  DEALLOCATE MyCursor
  ```

Comment: OK works great(+1), Thanks, If I want to get rid of these legacy cursors what is  the best choice to scan the table row by row?

Comment: @SNash the best choice is NOT to scan any table row by agonizing row. Looping in sql is horrible for performance.

Comment: I understand, . I need to update 4 other columns of each row based on a criteria. What do you suggest?

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to simply do it in the query:  UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = 'CID=' + t.ANumber + ' Avatar=' + t.BNumber FROM MyTable t WHERE <INCLUDEWHEREORELSETROUBLE>.

Basically in the 'From' clause you can join up any necessary tables to update the MyTable column properly.

Comment: And @SeanLange is right about looping, but a purist might argue that you don't even want to concatenate strings in a sql statement...that kind of work belongs on the application tier.  If you're in band-aid mode I wouldn't sweat the RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do a Select , it will return exactly what cursor returns but it will be much faster.

A simple select would look something like.....

```
select 'CID='+ CAST(Anumber AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' Avatar='+ CAST(BNumber  AS VARCHAR(100)) 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ANumber , date1
```

To also handle nulls I would do something like...

```
select 'CID='   + CAST(ISNULL(Anumber,'No value') AS VARCHAR(100)) 
    + ' Avatar='+ CAST(ISNULL(BNumber,'No value') AS VARCHAR(100)) 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ANumber , date1
```

Comment: Because the operation I need to do is row by row. I need to update 4 other columns of each row based on a criteria.

Comment: @SNash post another question for your `UPDATE` problem. Maybe it won't require using a `CURSOR`.